# SQL Server: how to set dynamic column name in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I am pretty new to dynamic proceddures and hope someone here can help me with the following.

It seems that my issue is with the AND part of my Where clause. I do not get an error here - it just doesnt return any results.

Edit: My dynamic column name would be "R.@searchCategory".

**My procedure so far:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
    @searchCategory nvarchar(100) = '',
    @searchTerm nvarchar(256) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN   

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)  
    SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100
                R.logID,
                R.flag,
                R.reviewer,
                R.modBy,
                A.Email AS requesterEmail,
                B.Email AS approverEmail,
                L.locale AS region,
                L.country AS countryName
    FROM        LogRequests R
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable A
    ON          A.NTID = R.requester
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable B
    ON          B.NTID = R.approver
    INNER JOIN   Locales_Countries L
    ON          R.country = L.isoCode
    WHERE       (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'') 
    AND         R.' + @searchCategory + ''' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
    ORDER BY    R.dateNeeded desc, R.dateRec desc, R.prio desc, R.EID desc
    FOR XML PATH(''requests''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT(''ranks'')'

    EXEC(@sql)

    END
END
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: I'm surprised this executes at all - you have an extra single quote, right after the @searchCategory that should make the statement throw a syntax exception. Also, you're really open to SQL Injection attacks with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many quotes in your AND statement...

Make this:

```
AND         R.' + @searchCategory + ''' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
```

Like this:

```
AND         R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
```

Outcome:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @searchCategory nvarchar(max), @searchTerm nvarchar(max)

set @searchCategory = 'something'
set @searchTerm = 'to look for'

    SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100
                R.logID,
                R.flag,
                R.reviewer,
                R.modBy,
                A.Email AS requesterEmail,
                B.Email AS approverEmail,
                L.locale AS region,
                L.country AS countryName
    FROM        LogRequests R
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable A
    ON          A.NTID = R.requester
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable B
    ON          B.NTID = R.approver
    INNER JOIN   Locales_Countries L
    ON          R.country = L.isoCode
    WHERE       (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'') 
    AND         R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''
    ORDER BY    R.dateNeeded desc, R.dateRec desc, R.prio desc, R.EID desc
    FOR XML PATH(''requests''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT(''ranks'')'

    print @sql
```

I always print my dynamic sql... and copy the output to a new window to see if anything is escaped that shouldn't be.

NB: Please research SQL Injection attacks, and use sp_executeSQL -- EXEC is bad practice.

Comment: That fixed it - awesome ! Thanks a lot - didn't expect it to be that easy. :) I will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

By the time I posted, there was already another correct answer: you added too many single quotes to the @sql definition.

One way of catching these simple errors is by adding `print @sql` so you can see how the query reads before you attempt to execute it. I included it in the modified script below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
    @searchCategory nvarchar(100) = '',
    @searchTerm nvarchar(256) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN   

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)  
    SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100
                R.logID,
                R.flag,
                R.reviewer,
                R.modBy,
                A.Email AS requesterEmail,
                B.Email AS approverEmail,
                L.locale AS region,
                L.country AS countryName
    FROM        LogRequests R
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable A
    ON          A.NTID = R.requester
    LEFT JOIN   EmpTable B
    ON          B.NTID = R.approver
    INNER JOIN   Locales_Countries L
    ON          R.country = L.isoCode
    WHERE       (R.logStatus LIKE ''%Completed%'' OR R.logStatus LIKE ''%Closed%'') 
    AND         R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%'' + @searchTerm + ''%''
    ORDER BY    R.dateNeeded desc, R.dateRec desc, R.prio desc, R.EID desc
    FOR XML PATH(''requests''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT(''ranks'')'

    --print @sql
    EXEC(@sql)

    END
END
```